# What is correct "by both voice or video chat" vs "with both voice or video chat"

Tags: sentence-construction, difference

I want to write about a website that we can talk at the same time with others by using voice or video chat because it is optional to use one of them, and I am not sure what can I use by or with in the sentence. for example.

> "It is the best website to find a lot of groups for practicing English speaking skills **by / with** using both voice or video chat."

Comment: I think the title was correct "by/with using both."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"By" works here, but "with" does not.

You might also be looking for the conjunction "[and/or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/And/or)", which means either one, or the other, or both:

> We can practice by using voice and/or video chat.